# C# Decrypt AES Mail EAGetMail / Chilkat

Tags: c#, email, encryption, aes

I try to decrypt a `AES` encrypted mail. I can receive the mail but when i save the Attachement it is a `smime.p7m` file but i cannot decrpyt it. I tried to use `Chilkat` or `EAGetMail` to decrpyt it.

Do I Need a certificate or private/public key?

```
 Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);
 Certificate oCert = new Certificate();
 oCert.Load("E:\\Programme\\Email_Verarbeitung\\tt.cer");
 try
 {
      oMail = oMail.Decrypt(oCert);
 }
 catch (Exception ert) { Log.writeLog(ert.Source + "_" + ert.Message); }
```

I get the Error-Message:

`EAGetMail20_Cannot find the certificate and private key to use for decryption`

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Is the private key in `tt.cer`?

Answer (score 1):

From the [EAGetMail documentation](http://www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/sdk/default.aspx?ct=objects):

> **pfx and cer**
>
> *.pfx certificate contains public/private key and *.cer only contains public key, so *.pfx is able to decrypt email while *.cer is used to
>   encrypted email only. *.pfx and *.cert can be exported by "Control
>   Pannel"->"Internet Options"->"Content"->"Certificates". If importing
>   private key is chosen, the *.pfx will be generated, otherwise *.cer
>   will be generated.

In order to decrypt you need the private key.  So, it seems that you should be using a `.pfx` file.